# "preseed/late_command" does not work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: automation, debian, ubuntu-14.04

I'm setting up an automatic install of Ubuntu 14.04, using preseed. I tested this using a virtual machine(virtualBox machine). Everything installs fine, without any questions, but I can't quite figure out how to use the late_command at the end of the preseed file.

What I want to do, at first time, is to run start.sh script.

I tried several attempts:

Here is the Code:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/start.sh /target/home/user; in-target chmod 700 /home/user/start.sh; /home/user/start.sh
```

Also:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string chroot /target; cp -f /cdrom/start.sh /home/user; chmod 700 /home/user/start.sh;
```

Third attempt:

```
 d-i preseed/late_command string cp -f /cdrom/start.sh /home/user; in-target chmod +x /home/user/start.sh; in-target sh start.sh
```

the script start.sh define one command:

```
#! /bin/sh 
echo "bonjour" > /home/user/bonjour_file
```

I have tried also to create a file after installation in the new machine:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target touch /etc/postinst_user.done

preseed preseed/late_command string in-target touch /etc/postinst_user.done
```

But it just hung at the very end of the installation. The installation was functional, but the script had not run at all and the file "postinst_user.done" had not created.

Is the newly installed file system mounted under /target? And what's the environment like at this point in the install. What would be the correct way to do this?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few days ago, so i thought i'd share the solution with you. When preseeding Ubuntu Installations, the

```
d-i preseed/late_command string yourcommand
```

command doesn't work. Instead you have to use

```
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string yourcommand
```

I hope this helps

Jan

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?  18.04.5 or 20.04?